# Mathematical calculation I want to resolve before executing a function

Tags: javascript

I have a math equation that I to resolve before I apply it to a function.

I have the following math equation that I want to resolve to true:

```
 console.log((3*(d[0]+d[3]+d[6])+7*(d[1]+d[4]+d[7])+1*(d[2]+d[5]+d[8]))%10 === 0);
```

Here is a literal of the expression:

```
console.log((3*(2+0+5)+7*(7+8+2)+1*(1+1+8))%10 === 0);
```

The literal expression resolves to true, but the expression with the variables, which insert the same numbers as the literal, results in false.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: *"but the expression with the variables [...] results in false"* – because the variables do not hold the same value that you think they do. If they did, the expressions would be identical.

Comment: In that case `d` looks different than you think.

Comment: Run a quick reality check on your assumptions there: `d.forEach((x,i) => console.log(i,typeof(x),x))`

Comment: Hi gents, that's what's throwing me off. I've done a check and have mapped the exact same digits to the variables. So the literal expression is actually the same as the dynamic.

Comment: Prove it by posting a complete example that reproduces the problem. Otherwise we're just speculating about issues we can't verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, `d` is a string and you like to calculate some check sum. In this case, you have to convert all data of the string to `Number` and make then the test with `dNum`.

```
dNum = d.split('').map(Number);
```

Comment: Reasonable assumption. Neat `map`.

Comment: Thanks David. Mapping the number did it!